# jquery | Change height of divs dynamically onresize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my function that calculate the height of each div section when page resize is occur. It show me the same height value after resuze. But everything is ok on first page loading. Where is a problem?

**JS**

```
$(document ).ready(function() {
   $(window).bind('orientationchange resize', function(e){
        resize();
   }).trigger('resize');
});

function resize() {
    var vph     = $(window).height();

    $.each($('.st-panel'), function( index, value ) {
        var section_height = $(this).height() < vph ? vph : $(this).height();
        $(this).height(section_height);
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="st-panel" id="st-panel-1">...long text here...</section>
<section class="st-panel" id="st-panel-2">...long text here...</section>
<section class="st-panel" id="st-panel-3">...long text here...</section>
<section class="st-panel" id="st-panel-4">...long text here...</section>
<section class="st-panel" id="st-panel-5">...long text here...</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there could be a problem with you business logic. When viewport size is increased, your sections are increased as well. Afterwards when it's decreased, sections' heights will always be greater than viewport size, that's why resize is not occurring.

I may be wrong, but you need to specify what are you trying to achieve to understand what exactly is broken.

You can have a look at this jsfiddle, I addded some logging there http://jsfiddle.net/q8sp2jzy/

```
console.log('Section height: '+ $(this).height());
console.log('Viewport: ' + vph);
var section_height = $(this).height() < vph ? vph : $(this).height();
$(this).height(section_height);
```